# How does this hub come apart?

Tags: hub, freewheel

Really, I have two questions.
But first, I see no place to put a wrench on this hub.
Well, there is one small notch on one side on the dust cap (on the other side).
How do I get this hub apart?  It's wobbly and I want to repack it.
[image]

The other problem, of course, is the several metal damage from my cassette.  Once I get it apart, I can see if it's possible to replace that part... we'll see.

Really, I'm just looking for the proper procedure to get this thing apart!

thanks!

Comment: Do you know a brand/model?

Comment: I would assume that some sort of socket-like wrench fits notches in the ends, similar to your standard freewheel wrench.  See http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/cassette-and-freewheel-removal, http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/freehub-service, and http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/hub-overhaul-and-adjustment .

Answer (score 4):

Its likely disassembles in one of two ways:

1. two cone wrenches (one on each side of the hub) to remove the jam nuts. This is the likely option. From your photo it looks like there is a flat spot on the jam nut.
2. two hex wrenches (one on each side of the hub) that fit into the axle end.

[image]

Two videos demonstrating these techniques:

- http://aol.it/15nYDub
- http://aol.it/Ioc7T2

Comment: looks like those video links are now dead. Thanks AOL =(

Answer (score 0):

Try putting either 8 or 6 mm hex wrenches in both axle ends and rotating counterclockwise.  A lot of newish hubs are simply held together with threaded composite axles..